# MS Access Outlook integration

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I'm just new to outlook. Can i do update/delete contacts,appointments,tasks to outlook using ms access? is it the same behavior with the all versions of outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this (and more) using VBA.

Examples:

[Getting Started with Outlook VBA](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=49)

[Using VBA to Manage Your Outlook Email Attachments](http://www.fontstuff.com/outlook/oltut01.htm)

[FnSendMailSafe](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning)

[Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 VBA Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221877(office.11).aspx)

Here's a typical snippet for creating a task (other items are done in a similiar way):

```
Dim myOlApp As Object
Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipients
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Set myDelegate = myItem.Recipients.Add("John Doe")
myItem.Subject = "Prepare Agenda For Meeting"
myItem.DueDate = #9/27/2009#
myItem.Save
myItem.Assign
myItem.Display
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch for the response.. What if i want to delete/update an item? How should i do that? Thanks